# OFFSET Function Issue Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I am trying to use the OFFSET function in Excel to pick up data from sheets and put it in the cell. I have this:

```
=OFFSET('140'!B$48,0,ROWS(Summary!L150))
```

When i copy down the cell to the below cell using the drag function; the `Summary!L150` changes to `Summary!L151` which is perfect however I also need it to change the sheet reference from '140' to '141' and keep counting up as i drag. I cannot seem to find away for it to change the sheet number up 1 with each new cell copy.

Eg:

Cell 1:

```
=OFFSET('140'!B$48,0,ROWS(Summary!L150))
```

Cell 2:

```
=OFFSET('141'!B$48,0,ROWS(Summary!L151))
```

Cell 3:

```
=OFFSET('142'!B$48,0,ROWS(Summary!L152))
```

Any advice here would be great as there are literally hundreds of sheets. Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the point of the ROWS function there - you could just put 1 instead. For the sheet name, you need INDIRECT and ROW or ROWS:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&Row(A140)&"'!B$48"),0,1)
```

for example.

Comment: Thank you. What does the A in (A140) reference? Thanks again

Comment: Beat me to it.. was just writing the text in the answer.  I think `ROWS(Summary!L150)` should just be `Summary!L150`  The [Rows](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/rows-function-b592593e-3fc2-47f2-bec1-bda493811597) function just returns the number of rows in the reference -  you're only referencing a single cell, so it will always return 1.

Comment: The [Row](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/row-function-3a63b74a-c4d0-4093-b49a-e76eb49a6d8d) function will return the row number of the referenced cell - so `A140` is a cell reference and `row` will return 140 from that.  You could just as easily use `XFD140` if you wanted.  The idea is the cell reference will increase by 1 as you drag down returning 140, 141, 142, etc..

Comment: This has worked perfectly. Thank you all very much for your time!